# How to change default homepage of strapi to default content-manager page

Tags: strapi

How to change strapi default dashboard to content-manager page . when we open strapi on local lost it should open content-manager page rather than dashboard page . can we do that on strapi v4.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a index file on `./public/index.html` and add this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/admin/content-manager'" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#redirecting-landing-page-to-admin-panel) for more details.

But I guess it would only work when opening the `http://localhost:1337/` and not any other url like `http://localhost:1337/admin`

Does that work for you?

Comment: No, It work only on http://localhost:1337/ for /admin it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/nginx-proxy#redirecting-landing-page-to-admin-panel

./config/middlewares.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => [
    // ...
    { resolve: './src/middlewares/admin-redirect' },
];
```

---

./src/middlewares/admin-redirect.js

```
module.exports = (_config, { strapi }) => {
    const redirects = ['/', '/index.html'].map((path) => ({
        method: 'GET',
        path,
        handler: (ctx) => ctx.redirect('/admin'),
        config: { auth: false },
    }));

    strapi.server.routes(redirects);
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).